# Expression engine 3 - plugin not being picked up

Tags: plugin, ee3, custom

I am trying to create a simple plugin, however EE is not picking it up so I cannot enable it.

```
class Age_gate
{
  public static $name         = 'Age Gate';
  public static $version      = '1.0';
  public static $author       = 'Me';
  public static $author_url   = 'http://example.com/';
  public static $description  = 'Makes people verify their age.';
  public static $typography   = FALSE;


    public $return_data = "";

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->return_data = "Hello World";
    }
}

/* End of file pi.plugin_name.php */
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to add a addon.setup.php file to the folder.
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/addon_setup_php_file.html